# What graphic driver? Acer 5750

Tags: drivers, graphics

I bought a new laptop, Acer 5750 and installed Ubuntu 11.10 on it.
Now I would like to know what graphic driver should I install for it. When I go to 'Aditional Drivers', it does not show any graphic drivers to be activated.

My graphic card is: Intel HD Graphics 3000.
Thanks in advance. :)

Answer (score 1):

Your drivers are included with the kernel. For this reason you do not have to install any proprietary drivers via 'Additional Drivers'.

If you would like you can add the following:

> sudo apt-get install mesa-utils

This will enable information to be displayed about your drivers in System Information.

I have never bothered though so it is totally optional to do so.

Answer (score 0):

Intel graphics drivers are open source and already included. If you'd like to test newer drivers, you can add [Fabio Pedretti's "Updated and Optimized Graphics Drivers" PPA](https://launchpad.net/~oibaf/+archive/graphics-drivers). Be aware that these drivers may be less stable than your current drivers. If you install the PPA, update your system and you're happy with the new drivers, you may wish to disable the PPA in Software Sources to prevent a future update from breaking things - this has happened to me before.

Entering this in the terminal will add the repository and upgrade all packages on your system to the latest version:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:oibaf/graphics-drivers -y && sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade -y
```